# In Bootstrap 5 how do i vertically move a button and have it still be functional?

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, bootstrap-5

i want to move the buttons for sign up with google,apple, and email under were it says join but they wont move or they dont work if i force it to move with css

[image: bottom of site]css

```
.homepage_topRight_Buttons{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;[![top of site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZa1Q.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZa1Q.png)
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.homepage_topRight_Buttons h3{
    margin-left:90%;
    margin-top: -10rem;
}

.homepage_topRight_Buttons button{
    width: 19rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.homepage_topRight_policies {
    width: 20rem;
    margin-left:56%;
    margin-right: 21rem;;
    margin-top: -0.23rem;
    font-size: 0.7rem;
    color: var(--grey-2);
}

.homepage_topRight_policies a {
    color: var(--bomber-primary);
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

React

```
<div className="row justify-content-center offset-7">  
          <div className="homepage_topRight_Buttons mb-5 col-xl-12 col-l-12 col-md-7 col-sm-9 col-xs-8 d-flex align-items-center ">
            <button className="primary_button">Sign up with Google</button>
            <button className="primary_button">Sign up with Apple</button>
            <button className="secondary_button">
              Sign up with phone or email
            </button> 
            <p className="homepage_topRight_policies">
              By signing up, you agree to the <a href="/">Terms of Service</a> and{""}
              <a href="/">privacy Policy</a>, including{""}
              <a href="/">cookie Use.</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
```

so far i tryed to use margin-top but it wont move, align-end but that didnt move anything, and went into the css file with margin-top and that moved it but disabled the button.

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out i forgot you can make custom css class names

```css
.mt-8-c{
    margin-top: -43.5rem;
}
```